# Best way to initialize model class members

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a better way to initialize model classes without explicitly defining each member with **undefined**?

The original idea was ability just to call `super(data);` in extended classes

```
class Model {
    construct(data: any) {
        Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
            this[key] = data[key];
        });
    }
}

class User extends Model {

    id: number = undefined;
    name: string = undefined;

    constructor(data: any) {
        super();
        this.construct(data);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand why you're doing what you're doing in your `construct` function.The `typeof data[key]` will be `undefined` if the value is undefined and `object` if the value is `null`, so there's no purpose to the `switch`...

Comment: Thank's! You right, there is my mistake with switch. But I want avoid many lines of code in each model when get data from backend it is why I make Model class for complex initializations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a constructor with optional parameters and public/private modifiers. In that way, you can call the constructor without parameters and still have a strong model.

```
class User {    
    constructor(public id?: any, public name? : any) {} 
}
```

this is equivalent to, but less verbose:

```
class User {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you want to convert an object to User, you can implement a bind method with assign:

```
class User {    
    constructor(public id?: any, public name? : any) {} 

    bind(object: any): Equipe {
        return Object.assign(this, object);
    }  

}
```

And finally, if you want a really strong model, you can use Object.seal in the bind method to not allow dynamic properties to be added to User:

```
class User {    
    constructor(public id?: any, public name? : any) {} 

    bind(object: any): Equipe {
        return Object.assign(Object.seal(this), object);
    }  
}
```

Now you can instantiate an User with:

```
let user = new User(); // user = {id: undefined, name: undefined}
```

and bind to another object:

```
let user = new User().bind({id: 1, name: 'bob'})
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use interfaces. Here's a link to a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMiciAK4C2ARtAApQD2ADgFxlW1QDcRpyAZzBRsDFuyEiQWXsVIhGYAEoQAjuWBQIAEwDKw0U2YB+CQemz+cBWHTQAcopXrNO-VKxiTZj7IC+REQANhBgyJQAnhjY7NHSyAC8eHzynPRG7ADMAIwATJm5ADQpJJKG4sgA5AASEEFBjJVEfrJEcCFQYAAUkXFYAHQUNOksAJSy7dDdvZjS-WXSXuNtHdNRswM2zhpaeuaeRsuEk50969j91op2UI7Kajtu+0vcQA) to demonstrate.

```
interface Thing {
    numberProp: number;
    stringProp: string;
    notRequiredStringProp?: string;
    anotherNotRequiredStringProp?: string;
}

let myThing: Thing = {
    numberProp: 31232,
    stringProp: 'Hello'
};

alert(myThing.numberProp);
alert(myThing.stringProp);
alert(myThing.notRequiredStringProp);
alert(myThing.anotherNotRequiredStringProp);
```

**EDIT**

Here's how you can access the data via a web service. There's no need to call a constructor.

```
export class ThingService {
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

   // Returns a collection of "Thing"
   getThings(): Observable<Thing[]>{
      return this.httpClient.get('api/things')
   }

   // Returns a "Thing" by it's unique identifier
   getThingById(id: number): Observable<Thing>{
      return this.httpClient.get('api/things/' + id)
   }
}
```

Then the usage, in a component perhaps could be:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.thingService.getThings().subscribe((things: Thing[]) => {
      //do something with things
  });
}
```

Comment: Indeed. This approach improves performance, maintainability, and reduces the possibility of myriad errors

Comment: When I get data from the backend, I just want to call `new User(userData)` to initialize, but the problem is that I have to explicitly define all the properties of the class to access it in the parent class. Is this the right way?

Comment: It's not working this way, because `things: Thing[]` will be just JSON, so i won't be able use getters, setters and class methods

Comment: You will still be able to get/set properties of `Thing`. You will not be able to use class methods on `Thing` because it is not a class. With this design pattern, the intention is to keep methods away from your models and encapsulated in a service that acts upon instance data. In the service example I posted, there is an implicit cast happening to the response data.

Answer (score -1):

if there is no logic you can simply do this in the constructor:

```
constructor( data: any){
     Object.assign(this, data);
}
```